# How to deliver variable of my jsp to my tag? (HTML)

Tags: java, html, jsp

I don't understand how I can deliver a value from a form in my jsp to my tag... I have tried it with a servlet and save it in a session, but i think the main problem is in my index and I don't know how to code it exactly.

this is my index.jsp:

```
    <form action="WunschServlet" method="post">

            <my:geschenk>

            <input type="text" name="wish"> 

            </my:geschenk>



</form>
```

In this form I'm putting in my "wish", which I will be checking in my created GeschenkTag.java:

```
public class GeschenkTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

private String wish;


public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {
    JspWriter out = getJspContext().getOut();
    PageContext pageContext = (PageContext) getJspContext();

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();

    wish = request.getParameter("wish");

    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i <= wish.length(); i++) {
        counter++;
    }

    if(counter > 10) {
        out.println("<p>" + "Ich hoffe das Geschenk {Geschenk} kann ich mir merken!" + "</p>");
    } else {
        out.println("<p>" + "Das kann ich besorgen" + "</p>");
    }

}
```

}

Before that i have saved my "wish" in a session in my WunschServlet.java:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String wish = request.getParameter("wish"); 
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    session.setAttribute("wish", wish);         
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);



}
```

I have already defined and initialized my tag, so thats not the problem. I just don't know how to get the wishinput to my tag

Comment: It's not clear for me the flow. When you call the index.jsp what do you see in yoir browser? Can.you see the inputbox named "wish"?

Comment: no i cant because it says Tag "(my:geschenk) must be empty" when i hover over my tag in my index.jsp.
I know theres something wrong with the coding in the index.jsp but i dont know how else to do it..

Comment: For "must be  empty" it could be a problem in your tld at 'body-content' tag. In general, if i Have understood what you want, delete the input element inside your tag and pass the Wish parameter to your tag as an attribute (you must modify tld)